# If $(G,*)$ is a group then for all $a, b \in G$, we have $(a*b)'=b'*a'$. Which would be the analogous expression for $(a*b'*b)'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the full problem:

> Show through calculations and the theorem $2.3$ that if $G$ is a group with binary operation $*$ then for all $a, b \in G$, we have $(a*b)'=b'*a'$. Which would be the analogous expression for $(a*b'*b)'$?

The theorem 2.3 that I'm refering to, is the existance of $a$ unique module ($e*a=a*e=a$) and inverse ($a'*a=a*a'=e$).

I have doubts in the process that I'm attempting to do. Here's what I got so far:

Given $a,b \in G$

$a*b$

$(a*b)$; associative (1)

$(a*b)\in G$

$(a*b)'*(a*b)=(a*b)*(a*b)'=e$; T2.3

$(a*b)*(a*b)'=e$

$(a*a'*b*b')*(a*b)'=e*a'*b'$; T2.3 (2)

$e*e*(a*b)'=a'*b'$

$(a*b)'=a'*b'$

$(a*b)'=b'*a'$; commutative (?) (3)

I'm starting my studies with group theory, so I'm not sure if I'm able to do what I did in (1), (2) and (3). Any help in finding a different way to solve this and the final question?

Comment: Is $a'$ the inverse of $a$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're right

Comment: $(a*b)' = (a*b)'*e = (a*b)'*a*a' =(a*b)'*a*e*a' = (a*b)'*a*b*b'*a'=  (a*b)'*(a*b)*b'*a'= e* b'*a' = b'*a'$

Comment: Thanks @Maksim, that was really helpful

Comment: Incidentally, your second use of 2.3, going from $(a*b)*(a*b)' = e$ to $(a*a'*b*b')*(a*b)'=e*a'*b'$, is where the mistake in your effort lies; you can't simply insert your $a'$ and $b'$ at arbitrary locations on the LHS.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you for pointing that out. Just yesterday in class I noticed something related with that: that there's even a weker structure of a gruop, which would allowed only propeties on the LHS.

Answer (score 3):

(*NB:* Not every group is commutative. Consider the [dihedral group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6) $D_3$ for example.)

---

We have

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{(ab)}\color{blue}{(b^{-1}a^{-1})}&=a((bb^{-1})a^{-1})\\
&=a(ea^{-1})\\
&=aa^{-1}\\
&=e
\end{align}$$

and, similarly, $\color{blue}{(b^{-1}a^{-1})}\color{red}{(ab)}=e$; thus your theorem gives that $\color{red}{(ab)}^{-1}=\color{blue}{b^{-1}a^{-1}}$.

---

Since $b^{-1}b=e$, we get $(ab^{-1}b)^{-1}=(ae)^{-1}=a^{-1}.$